# .NET Core c# Project - where does all nuget packages are located?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, nuget

I have created ASP.net Core project using Visual studio 2017.
I need to compile/debug this project on Build machine using Visual studio 2017. But I don't have internet on build machine.

I have **exact same project** on my dev machine that I can build with full internet access. I have full internet access on dev machine.

How do I copy all reference Nuget packages to Build machine so that I can compile/debug application on Build machine?

In .net framework project, I could copy entire 'packages' folder and it would work. While in .NET core there is no packages folder.

I tried copying packages from my dev machine's C:\Users<user>.nuget to C:\Users<user>.nuget of build machine (which doesn't have internet) which didn't work.

thanks,
atul

Comment: When you say "it didn't work", what was the error?

Comment: Nuget packages are stored in `C:\Users\<user>\.nuget\packages`. You will have to copy them to a directory on your build machine, then set it as a local package source in Visual Studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone spending time answering. that gave me many hints to look at.
Following settings in **C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config** solved my problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageRestore>
    <add key="enabled" value="True" />
    <add key="automatic" value="True" />
  </packageRestore>
  <bindingRedirects>
    <add key="skip" value="False" />
  </bindingRedirects>
  <packageManagement>
    <add key="format" value="0" />
    <add key="disabled" value="False" />
  </packageManagement>
  <disabledPackageSources>
    <add key="Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages" value="true" />
    <add key="custom" value="true" />
  </disabledPackageSources>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="Package source" value="C:\Users\myusername\.nuget\packages" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

Originally, it had following entries which was causing problem as machine didn't have internet access.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
    <add key="artifactory" value="https://<artifactory URL>/artifactory/api/nuget/v3/nuget-remote" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

All the packages are manually copied to build machine into C:\Users\myusername\.nuget\packages folder.

Comment: After above changes, i could see obj\project.assets.json with following reference "packageFolders": {
    "C:\\Users\\myusername\\.nuget\\packages\\": {},
    "C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\sdk\\NuGetFallbackFolder": {}
  }

Answer (score 1):

Add Nuget.config file in your root directory where the solution situated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
   <packageSources>
     <clear />
     <add key="PackageSource" value="c:\packages" />
   </packageSources>
 </configuration>
```

And you can use this command to build your project

```
dotnet restore $PROJECT_NAME --configfile ./NuGet.config
dotnet build $PROJECT_NAME --no-restore
```

Comment: I tried that. but didn't work. it was always throwing error -error NU1101: Unable to find package NuGet.Frameworks. No packages exist with this id in source(s): PackageSource